# Is there a way to get unique jacoco .exec file names?

Tags: continuous-integration, jacoco, circleci, jacoco-maven-plugin

Currently at my internship, I have my Jacoco-Maven plugin set up such that after the unit and integration reports are generated, they are merged into one.

Now, adding CircleCI into the mix, we run parallel jobs for our tests. These jobs cause only longest running test's .exec file to be read as the basis for the report, meaning all other tests are ignored, and our coverage would be lowered.

I thought the solution would be to have unique names, and then just merge all .exec file using a wildcard character within my POM, but there seems to be no documentation on it.